# Highlight Source Data Cell When Selecting Query Result Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to highlight source data cell when selecting query result cell.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NLIQBOu4izeKELIUyQLSpx_c9v87EW9TmRnuRaMOkwU/edit?usp=sharing

Race spreadsheet shared.

We want to highlight the appropriate source cell in column A when the QUERY result is selected in columns H:L.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, your shared spreadsheet cannot be accessed. Please fix permissions.

Comment: OK Thanks! Just fixed.